# Multiple outliers for two variable linear regression

Tags: linear-algebra, st.statistics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

**Problem**

Visually, the "extreme" outliers in the following graph are somewhat obvious:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z9kX.png]

**Question**

Given:

- ***T*** - Set of all temperatures
- ***Y*** - Set of all years
- Σ***T*** - Sum of temperatures.
- Σ***Y*** - Sum of years.
- N - Number of elements
- ***T***(n) - Temperature of the nth element in the temperature set

How do you determine if ***T***(n) is an outlier?

**Related Sites**

The math on some of these sites is a bit above my understanding:

- [Multiple Outliers Detection Procedures in Linear Regression (broken link)](http://myais.fsktm.um.edu.my/5723/)
- [M-estimator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator)
- [Measure of Surprise for Outlier Detection](http://home.ubalt.edu/ntsbarsh/Business-stat/opre504.htm#routlier)
- [Ordinary Least Squares Linear Regression](http://www.clockbackward.com/2009/06/18/ordinary-least-squares-linear-regression-flaws-problems-and-pitfalls/)

Many thanks!

Comment: Although I find the question to be interesting and profound, I removed the set-theory tag, since I don't find it applicable. Perhaps the question could be further retagged?

Comment: If you are looking for practical approaches to outlier removal, you might like to read the answers to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6819/regression-problem-detect-outliers. If you are interested in a philosophical discussion about when it is appropriate to remove outliers (if it ever is) then it appears that Joel might be interested in such a discussion -).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might suggest LTS, the Least Trimmed Squares, approach. there is code in fortran and matlab, the latter called fastlts, both produced, I believe, by Rousseuw's group. The method essentially minimizes the error of fit for a proportion of the data points, with the rest (outliers) ignored. The outliers are found by something like the Minimum Volume Ellipsoid method (roughly, find the ellipsoid of minimum volume containing 1/2 the points).

hth,

Answer (score 0):

Douglas Hawkins' book *Identification of Outliers* is not up to date unless it's been edited since last I looked, but it might give you some idea of the issues involved, no awareness of which is apparent in Steven Pav's answer.

(BTW, I'd have called this a one-variable linear regression; I was surprised to see what it was, given the subject heading.)